# how can I delete partial entry in excel

Tags: excel

My Excel sheet looks like this:

147(abc)

133(2011)

177(1a0)

This is how I want to change:

147

133

177

Comment: try to google your question before posting it here so you don't take the pain of writing up a question.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible with a formula. Something like:

> =LEFT(A1,FIND("(",A1)-1)

(copied down) with the `A1` reference adjusted if necessary.

(Then copy the results, Paste Special Values over the top and you can delete the source data.)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I just tried your formula and some cells returned "#value!". Maybe it only works with strings? Or am I missing something?  Sorry for the follow-up question.

Comment: You'll get #value if the cell doesn't have an opening parenthesis. Wrap it in an IFERROR like this: `=IFERROR(LEFT(A1,FIND("(",A1)-1),A1)`

Comment: It worked!! You freed me from manual editing.  Again, thank you so much!!

Comment: @pnuts, when I saw OP's comment about #value, I figured that was the issue. +1, nice answer, BTW.

Comment: #VALUE! was for cells without "(" and IFERROR works great! Thank you.

Comment: Maybe somebody was irritated because you answered a question they didn't deem worth of stackoverflow. Who knows? I wish all downvotes required an explanation. You linked to some gnarly formulas!

Answer (score 0):

Double click on individual cells in your excel sheet & edit them.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But I have about 8,000*24 cells!! I don't think manually editing the cell is how I want to do it.

Comment: This should be part of your question, this changes everything !! You need to write a script for that